# Parsing Multiple URLS through DOM. PHP @$dom->loadHTML($html.$html2);

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to parse 2 urls using the PHP DOM. I wondering if anyone could provide me with insight on where I went wrong? Is it not possible to parse both URLS as I've done below?

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.reddit.com/r/funny');
$html2 = file_get_contents('http://www.9gag.com/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html.$html2);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hyperlinks = $xpath->evaluate('//a[@class="thumbnail "]');
$hyperlinks2 = $xpath->evaluate('//a[@class="badge-item-img"]');

foreach($hyperlinks as $hyperlink) {
 if(strpos($hyperlink->getAttribute('href'), 'http://i.imgur.com/') !== FALSE){
echo "<img style='padding-left:30%' width=\"500\" src=\"" . $hyperlink->getAttribute('href') . "\" alt=\"\" />";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";

}
  else{
       echo "";
  }
}
?>
```

**EDIT** This edit has been added as I'm trying to do the compare for the class="badge-item-img" and it's not returning anything. Is it not possible to do it the way I'm doing this?

```
<?php
// Init the '$url_array' array.
$url_array = array();
$url_array[] = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/funny';
$url_array[] = 'http://www.9gag.com/';

// Init the return '$ret' array.
$ret = array();

// Roll through the '$url_array' array.
foreach ($url_array as $url_value) {
  $html = file_get_contents($url_value);
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTML($html);

  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2);
  $hyperlinks = $xpath->evaluate('//a[@class="thumbnail "]');
  $hyperlinks2 = $xpath2->evaluate('//a[@class="badge-item-img"]');

  foreach($hyperlinks as $hyperlink) {
    if(strpos($hyperlink->getAttribute('href'), 'http://i.imgur.com/') !== FALSE){
      $ret[] = "<img style='padding-left:30%' width=\"500\" src=\"" . $hyperlink->getAttribute('href') . "\" alt=\"\" />"
             . "<br>"
             . "<br>"
             . "<br>"
             ;

    }
    foreach($hyperlinks2 as $hyperlinker) {
            $ret[] = "<img style='padding-left:30%' width=\"500\" src=\"" . $hyperlinker->getAttribute('href') . "\" alt=\"\" />"
             . "<br>"
             . "<br>"
             . "<br>"
             ;
    }
  } 
  }
// Roll through the '$ret' array.
foreach($ret as $ret_value) {
  echo $ret_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to combine contents of one HTML file on top of another. Which would end up with a document that would most likely choke the DOM parser.  Instead, you should perhaps loop through the URLs & then output the results:

```
<?php

// Init the '$url_array' array.
$url_array = array();
$url_array[] = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/funny';
$url_array[] = 'http://www.9gag.com/';

// Init the return '$ret' array.
$ret = array();

// Roll through the '$url_array' array.
foreach ($url_array as $url_value) {
  $html = file_get_contents($url_value);
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTML($html);

  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $hyperlinks = $xpath->evaluate('//a[@class="thumbnail "]');
  $hyperlinks2 = $xpath->evaluate('//a[@class="badge-item-img"]');

  foreach($hyperlinks as $hyperlink) {
    if(strpos($hyperlink->getAttribute('href'), 'http://i.imgur.com/') !== FALSE){
      $ret[] = "<img style='padding-left:30%' width=\"500\" src=\"" . $hyperlink->getAttribute('href') . "\" alt=\"\" />"
             . "<br>"
             . "<br>"
             . "<br>"
             ;
    }
  }
}

// Roll through the '$ret' array.
foreach($ret as $ret_value) {
  echo $ret_value;
}

?>
```

Comment: See my edit above... It explains further what I meant by the question. I have implemented your solution in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see the problem.  I tested this code locally and it works.  Are you receiving an error of some kind?